Cannot launch app with capabilities noReset='true'
Here is the sample code from Appium, if I add noReset='true', then the app is not launched, and test failed. Remove it everything works fine.
The context is that in some tests, I don't want to clear the app cache. But it seems this noReset is broken, please help.
Appium: 2.5.3
Python: 3.12
Appium-Python-Client: 4.0.0

import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

capabilities = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    automationName='uiautomator2',
    deviceName='Android',
    appPackage='com.android.settings',
    appActivity='.Settings',
    language='en',
    locale='US',
    noReset='true' # comment this line, the app could be launched
)

appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'

class TestAppium(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities))

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

    def test_find_battery(self) -> None:
        el = self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//*[@text="Battery"]')
        el.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


I think you can not use noReset or fullReset options when automating OS or Bundled apps like com.android.settings which is the Device settings. And there is no problem with it since we are not responsible to test OS shipped apps. In all other apps you should have such a problem.
